# Update my existing column with single mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having following table data.

```
--------------
|ID | status |
--------------
| 1 |   0    |  
| 2 |   1    |
| 3 |   1    |  
| 4 |   0    |      
| 5 |   1    |
| 6 |   0    |
| 7 |   1    |
| 8 |   1    |
| 9 |   0    |
--------------
```

Now some of technical reason I want to update my table data records where `0` to `N` and `1` to `Y` so any one have idea how can I do with in single update query.

expected result:

```
--------------
|ID | status |
--------------
| 1 |   N    |  
| 2 |   Y    |
| 3 |   Y    |  
| 4 |   N    |      
| 5 |   Y    |
| 6 |   N    |
| 7 |   Y    |
| 8 |   Y    |
| 9 |   N    |
--------------
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `status` is a string, you would just do:

```
update t
    set status = (case when status = '0' then 'N' else 'Y' end)
    where status in ('0', '1');
```

If `status` is numeric, you would first need to alter its type.

Comment: I would mention `where status in ('0', '1');` is optional if only those 2 status.

Answer (score 2):

U can use below query if u having only 0 and 1 in status field. and if datatype of status field is INT then change it to varchar.

```
update `order` SET status = CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
update 'tablename' set status= if(status=0,'N','Y') where status in('0','1');
```

Make sure your field type is varchar for status